# Adding a TextCell to a Grid row in Xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Can someone tell me why adding the TextCell the way I do keeps giving me an error? Can TextCells not be directly added to a row?  Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NameDisplay"
             x:Class="NameDisplay.MainPage">

    <Grid ColumnSpacing="5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Text="Names Added" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <TextCell Text="TextCell" Detail="Test" DetailColor="Green" Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>


        <Grid Grid.Column="1"
              BackgroundColor="Black"/>

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a Label

Answer (score 0):

Cells are only intended to be used in ListViews and TableViews.